# How can I fetch user ID after overriding it with different primary key in Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel

User model is returning `id=null`, while debug I found out the the reason behind this issue is that in my `User` model I override the `$primary_key` with a custom one

#### User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    // Set the primary key to the generated version instead of the regular ID
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_code';
    // Set the key type
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    // Diable the auto-increment option
    public $incrementing = false;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_code',
        'fname',
        'mname',
        'lname',
        'email',
        'dob',
        'age',
        'gender',
        'insurance_number',
        'ssn',
        'avatar',
        'is_active',
        'userable_id',
        'userable_type',
    ];
}
```

I have the following code that generate a new `user_code` that uses the `id`

```
$user = new User;
$user = $user->create([
    'fname' => $request->fname,
    'lname' => $request->lname,
    'email' => $request->email,
]);
// Save the user in the DB
// Generate a usercode for the newely created user
$userCode = "ur" . date('y') . date('m') . $user->id;
```

Users Migration:

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_code')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('fname')->default('tbd');
            $table->string('mname')->default('tbd');
            $table->string('lname')->default('tbd');
            $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->date('dob')->default('1000-01-01');
            $table->integer('age')->default(0);
            $table->string('gender')->default('tbd');
            $table->integer('insurance_number')->default(0);
            $table->integer('ssn')->default(0);
            $table->string('avatar')->default('tbd');
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(false);
            $table->string('userable_code')->default('tbd');
            $table->string('userable_type')->default('tbd');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

`$user->id` is returning null, why such behavior is happening?

Comment: Changed the Variable of crated $user changes this with another variable name

Comment: You're gonna have to rethink your approach; if you change the `primary_key` to `user_code`, `$user->id` is never going to return a value unless you explicitly set one. If you're then trying to set a `user_code` based on the date plus an id, you're going to end up with duplicate `user_code` values very quickly.

Comment: as @TimLewis said what you are doing is wrong, but if i understood  correctly, you want to generate a unique code for each user, if that's the case, i would recommend keeping the normal Id (auto increment )  while having a dynamic attribute that generates the user_code , in your case ("ur" + created_at + userid), unless you want to use the code for querying

Comment: @TimLewis but in the DB the `id` is present and it still increments! why should set one?

Comment: @TimLewis I don't think there is any problem having an autoincrement field in the table that is not the primary key.  You'll still (automatically) get an ID, AFAIK?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm actually not sure; this isn't a situation I've run into before. Generally, if I have an auto-increment; it's the ID (and primary key), and this "other field" is generated from a combination of something like the date + id. This sounds backwards to me...

Comment: @TimLewis My idea is that the `user_code` will be for e.g UR19011 where 19 is the current year, 01 is current month and finally 1 is the `id` that is auto-incremented

Comment: @alihussein Yes, I understand that, but if you're trying to use `user_code` as the primary key, you can't, since it can't be `null`, and you require the row to be in the database to get the value of `id`. Do you follow?

Comment: @TimLewis yes that's why i'm saving the record without the `user_code` first with the `create()` method then i'm generating the `user_code` and update the record with it.

Comment: But you can't save it with `create()` (at least you shouldn't be able to) as the primary key will be null...

Comment: @TimLewis you are right! i was checking my DB `users` table structure and i noticed that `id` still indicated as the primary key and `user_code` as index!! i did `migrate:refresh` and still the same

Comment: There we go. Can you take a second to edit that migration into your question? (at a minimum the relevant columns). Should be easier to reference if we need to.

Comment: @TimLewis's right. You can't save a model with a blank primary key.  I updated my answer.

Comment: @TimLewis I've added the User migration to the question

Comment: Thank you; that's very helpful. I believe that using `->increments()` in your migration sets `id` to the `primary_key`, which means you have a mismatch on your `User` model and your `users` table. If we go back to the first comment I posted here, I would recommend leaving `id` as the `primary_key`, and allowing `user_code` to be `nullable` and `unique`; if you did that, the code you have now should work without issue.

Comment: @TimLewis ok will try this and see the results

Comment: Whatever works for you; the accepted answer is perfectly fine, but yeah, just something to be aware of in the future.

Comment: @TimLewis tried your solution and it worked fine, i guess i'm gonna apply this to all the other models. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set `$user` as a new model instance:

```
$user = new User;
```

But then you're trying to create a new user from that instance, that won't work:

```
$user = $user->create([ ...
```

Since that doesn't work, you're not really saving anything to the DB, and you won't get an ID.

The second part of your problem is (as @TimLewis pointed out in the comments) that you are trying to create and save a model with a blank primary key (`user_code`).  That won't work, so you'll need to work out what the ID is *before* trying to save it.

```
// Remove this line:
// $user = new User;

// Find the current highest ID:
$last = User::max('id');

// Your new user will have this ID
$newID = $last->id + 1;

// And just use the normal way to create and save a model:
$user = User::create([
    'userCode'  => "ur" . date('y') . date('m') . $newID,
    'fname'     => $request->fname,
    'lname'     => $request->lname,
    'email'     => $request->email,
]);
```

Comment: It's an odd mix of approaches. You can do `$user = new User; $user->whatever = "whatever"; $user->save();`, or you can do `$user = User::create(["whatever" => "whatever"]);`. Both methods will result in a `User`, but not when combined (i.e. `$user = new User; $user = $user::create([...]);`)

Comment: @TimLewis Exactly, and therein lies the problem :-)

Comment: Half of the problem :P See the comments to the actual question above.

Comment: yes, forgive my mistake i was using the `$user->save()` method and than i tried `App\User::create()` and things got little messed up. anyways, i tried the `User::create()` and still got the `id=null`!!

Comment: @alihussein Does your record get saved to the DB? Does it have an ID in the DB? Is your ID field specified as `-> autoIncrement()` in your migration?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes it is saved with an `id` but without the `user_code` due to the null issue. this is the line from my `users` migration:

`$table->increments('id');`

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't actually *save* your `user_code` - are you saving it somewhere?  You need to do 2 database operations: 1st save to generate an ID, 2nd step to use that ID in your `user_code` and save it

Comment: @alihussein I've updated my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes there are couple of lines that update the record i didn't add them, i tried your solution and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I may not know what you are trying to achieve here, but I'm just assuming that this is a very special use case.

Try this:

```
// Notice how we are using the User as a class, not instantiating it.
$user = User::create([
    'fname' => $request->fname,
    'lname' => $request->lname,
    'email' => $request->email,
]);

// Save the user in the DB
// Generate a usercode for the newely created user
$userCode = "ur" . date('y') . date('m') . $user->id;
```

This assumes that your `id` column in your database table is still `INCREMENTS` and `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: still i got `id=null`